# Neo4j/Graph DBS Performance for Rapidly Updated/Changing Nodes/Relations

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, recommendation-engine

I'm currently in the early processes of evaluating and building a recommendation engine for a project I'm working on. I currently have data stored in Redshift and I was considering using using Neo4j to build my engine. However due to the nature of my project requiring essentially realtime updates and deletion of nodes and relationships I am concerned about about losing performance over time. Essentially a new product will only last up for a an hour or so before being removed and in order for it to scale will require new nodes (products) to be created, new relations (users who viewed product), and just a quickly for these to be deleted as they are no longer online.

Any thoughts on the applicability of neo4j/Graph DBs for this would be much appreciative.

Comment: Neo4j works great for real-time updates. What scale are you looking to achieve? (how many new products per second, deletions per second, new relationships per second, etc)

Comment: Oh great

Up to 100000s or more. With majority of those recycling (coming on and off) in a matter of hours. I only want to keep track of those which are online at the time if that makes sense?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? Neo4j 2.2+ achieves such write speeds on appropriate hardware but it seems a bit off for a graph database to ingest event stream data directly without any preprocessing / filtering.